# Overwrite Windows XP with Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-xp

I have a Compaq Mini 110C with Windows XP. I'd like to run Ubuntu on it instead. It's a very old computer and I can't log into it as I don't remember my password. I don't care about any of the software or files on the computer.

Is there a way to install Ubuntu so that it overwrites XP where I don't have to log in to install it? The computer doesn't have a disk drive.

Comment: Yes, although check it can boot from USB first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: If it is old computer, I would go with some Ubuntu's lightweight flavour. And about XP password... its pretty simple to exploit...

Comment: I thing that the only scenario there you would log in to XP, is **one of** the methods to install Ubuntu alongside XP.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was posted some times ago:

[Best Ubuntu version for my netbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259051/best-ubuntu-version-for-my-netbook)

Dont forget that this is not a PC but a netbook so a full version of Ubuntu can disapoint you by his responce time.

To check if the netbook is able to boot on a USB stick you could need to enter the CMOS and change the boot sequence.
http://dfarq.homeip.net/2011/01/how-to-make-hp-and-compaq-computers-boot-off-usb/

Best

Comment: Or net boot, but then you will need another computer acting as a boot server.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Using the unetbootin software you can create a bootable thumb drive from the ISO. Boot using this thumb drive. On the install wizard, select Erase disk and install Ubuntu option. This is clear out the entire drive and install ubuntu on it. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: If you can not set the computers boot device, because you no longer know the bios password, then you need to investigate how you can reset it (it varies by computer).

Answer (score 0):

I have this same computer. It works OK with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as long as I use the 2d desktop. Pretty slow with the 3d desktop. Since the new versions of Ubuntu don't have the 2d desktop, I strongly suggest installing Lubuntu (or Xubuntu, but I have no experience with that flavor).

To boot off the USB on this computer, just restart, and press F9 as soon as the text prompt appears. Then select the USB in the menu that appears.

Comment: Note the `L', `X`, `K` etc variants of Ubuntu are just a difference in **default** packages that are installed. Therefore you can migrate to a different variant by installing the appropriate packages, and optional removing the old. Though on a powerful enough computer you can have two or more people logged in at the same time using different variants of the desktop.